# Alias to create a Python package

Tags: command-line, bash, python, alias, zsh

Wondering how to create an alias for creating a Python package. A Python package is nothing more than a folder with an empty `__init__.py` file inside it. So basically I need something like `alias pydir="mkdir {dirname};cd {dirname};touch __init__.py"`. Is that something I can do with an alias? I'm using zsh if that matters. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted was a function. Here's what I came up with if anyone's interested:
`pydir () { mkdir $1; touch $1/__init__.py; }`